# Should I do add_action for child function in extends class?

Tags: php, class

- The Base Class has add_action for the parent function.
- In the extends Class, the child function has the same name and use parent::
  to make it clearly a child.

Do I still need to do add_action for the child in the extends Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need, every extended class has the same methods as it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

No if there is not needed to change function logic :-)